# util:CloseApplication from Windows service

Tags: winapi, wix, windows-installer

I am trying to close "Tray Application" during updating my application. Functionality to close tray from "Windows Service" looks like this:

```
<util:CloseApplication 
  Id="CloseTrayAgent"
  Target="$(var.TrayAgentBinName).exe"
  RebootPrompt="no"
  CloseMessage="yes"
  Description="Tray application is still running"/>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="WixCloseApplications" Before="RemoveFiles" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

That scenario works if update is invoked from "User" (just from user console) but it does not work if it is invoked from "Windows Service".
I checked msi log but it seems to me there is no errors.

Where is my mistake? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried any of the other close options, e. g. `ElevatedCloseMessage`, `EndSessionMessage`, `ElevatedEndSessionMessage`?

Comment: Yes, I have checked all of them... (EndSessionMessage="yes", ElevatedCloseMessage="yes", ElevatedEndSessionMessage="yes", CloseMessage="yes")

Comment: Thinking about it, [a service normally runs in session 0, which is isolated from user sessions](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/voy/2007/02/23/services-isolation-in-session-0-of-windows-vista-and-longhorn-server/). Therefore it's not possible to send a windows message from the service to the tray app. You have to use another mechanism, e. g. an [event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396(v=vs.85).aspx) that you create in the global namespace. You could create this event in a DLL custom action.

Comment: It's frustrating is that wixtoolset does not have functionality to achive that goal. That's what I'm trying to do now... winapi event + custom action + *.dll

Comment: I suggest to [create an issue on github](https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+CloseApplication+) as running an update installer from a service is quite common use case. Maybe `CloseApplication` can be extended to support setting an event. Something like `CloseEvent="MyEventName"`.

Comment: @zett42 when you run an installer from a service, don't run it in the service's own session, run it in a user's session instead. `CreateProcessAsUser()` with a user token from an active session can do that. Then Wix can send messages to apps in the same session.

Comment: @RemyLebeau There might be multiple user sessions active (fast user switching). The tray program might run in one of them or even both. Do you suggest running the installer in each session?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I think in that case user permission issue may occur (e.g. standard user do not have permission to install win service etc.)

Comment: @zett42 if the installer affects each user individually, then yes. Otherwise, if it affects the system globally, then it shouldn't matter which user session runs it, so long as it gets run as an elevated admin.

Comment: @definename the service can run the installer as an admin within a specific user session. Or, have the service spawn a utility process as the session user (the service could run its own EXE with special command-line parameters, if you don't want to write a separate EXE), and then that process can run the installer, allowing Windows to prompt for elevation if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Services run in session zero, which is isolated from the interactive desktop session. This article explicitly points out the issue with services that use APIs like SendMessage to send a message to a an app running in the interactive session:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2007/04/27/application-compatibility-session-0-isolation/

A search for -services session isolation- or -session 0- will give more information.